# Firebug refusing to run with Pixel Perfect in Firefox v3.5.6, v3.5.7 and v3.6

Tags: firefox, firebug

I was using `Firefox v3.5.6` with `Firebug v1.5` and `Pixel Perfect` and everything was fine. But today, suddenly `Firebug` refused to start and run. They seem to run fine when either of the plug-in is disabled, but if `Firebug` runs, `Pixel Perfect` won't open and vice versa. Mind you, I did not upgrade my `Firefox`. So, I tried upgrading it to the newer `Firefox v3.6`. But, in vain, same issue exists in the newer version too.
 Has anyone being facing a similar thing?
Any idea why such a weird thing is happening despite no software updates or configuration change??

Comment: Have you YSlow installed, too? The 2.0.5 crashes FF from time to time. Perhaps this could be a side effect...

Comment: No I have no other Firefox Plug-in installed except Firebug and Pixel Perfect!!

Comment: Update: Pixel Perfect is not showing any overlays at all! I think the problem lies with PP and not in Firebug.

Comment: firequery was crashing firebug on firefox 3.5.7+

Comment: i never installed Firequery ever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new version of Pixel Perfect has been released (v1.5.6). And it is now working normally as it is supposed to. I'm back on track!!